# Select Encadeado entre duas tabelas usando de critério o campo da primeira

Tags: sql, select, firebird

Boa tarde, grandes mestres.

A situação é a seguinte, preciso tirar da tebela **d12400** todos os resultados do campo **nrentg** em que o campo **dtentg** seja = '13.10.2020', para buscar na tabela **d12410** os campos que **d12400.nrenr** = **nrentg** e exibir o campo **nrentg** e **cdpro**.

tentei variações disto
`select cdpro, nrentg from d12410 where nrentg = (select nrentg from d12400 where dtentg = '13.10.2020')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Já tentou utilizar uma junção?

```
SELECT codpro, nrentg 
FROM d12410 JOIN d12400 ON (d12410.nrentg = d12400.nrentg)
WHERE d1240.dtentg = '13.10.2020'
```